# Reduce array of coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates

I track the users location in my app to a database with all the coordinates. I then do some stuff to select a range of coordinates in a time frame, but when I save it to the server is takes a long time due to the big amount of data. (15 minutes is 900 `CLCoordinate2D`'s and that is quite a bit).

What I wanna do is to remove the coordinate which are intersected by the preceding and following coordinate. Using overly simple coordinates for illustration purposes, but imagine this being done on real coordinates in an array of a couple thousand objects.

Example:

```
0,0 //Keep
1,1 //Drop
2,2 //Drop
3,3 //Keep
3,4 //Keep
4,4 //Keep
5,3 //Keep
```

Or, shitty visualized: 
 [image]

I know I should probably use some vector stuff, but I am not good at maths.
How can I reduce this array to remove the obsolete points?

Comment: Are they evenly spaced in time?

Comment: Location Manager with BestForNavigation gives an update roughly every 1 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this...

```
var coordTimes:[(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, time: Double)] = []
// ...
func appendCoord(newCoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, newTime: Double) {
    guard coordTimes.count > 1 else {
        coordTimes.append((newCoord, newTime))
        return
    }
    let n = coordTimes.count
    // So there are at least two already in the array
    let c0 = coordTimes[n - 2].coord
    let t0 = coordTimes[n - 2].time
    let c1 = coordTimes[n - 1].coord
    let t1 = coordTimes[n - 1].time
    let dt = t1 - t0
    let dtNew = newTime - t0

    guard (dtNew > 0) && (dt > 0) else {
        // decide what to do if zero time intervals. Shouldn't happen
        return
    }
    // Scale the deltas by the time interval...
    let dLat = (c1.latitude - c0.latitude) / dt
    let dLon = (c1.longitude - c0.longitude) / dt
    let dLatNew = (newCoord.latitude - c0.latitude) / dtNew
    let dLonNew = (newCoord.longitude - c0.longitude) / dtNew

    let tolerance = 0.00001 // arbitrary - choose your own
    if (abs(dLat - dLatNew) <= tolerance) && (abs(dLon - dLonNew) <= tolerance) {
        // Can be interpolated - replace the last one
        coordTimes[n - 1] = (newCoord, newTime)
    } else {
        // Can't be interpolated, append new point
        coordTimes.append((newCoord, newTime))
    }
}
```

The tolerance is important, as you are very unlikely to get exactly matching intervals. Also, for the geodesists amongst you, there is no need to convert into map coordinates or calculate true distances, as the OP simply wants to know if the coordinates can be interpolated.

Comment: This looks promising, will test it out right away. I dont see the relevance of time though. Maybe I should've been more descriptive, but the locations are already saved and sorted from oldest to newest, not appended on the fly.

Comment: If that's the case, just replace time with the original index number (not the compressed index number)